# jquery ui dialog redirect on close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to force a dialog to close after it was initialized. This is how the dialog is initially created

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    width: 960,
    hide: 'slide',
    position: 'top',
    show: 'slide'
});
```

The reason why I'm not attaching the event to the above code is that I do not want the dialog to always redirect on close. I only want the redirecting to happen manually. I am trying to use this code after the dialog is displayed but it does not work.

```
   $("#myDialog").dialog({
        close: function(event, ui) { location.href = 'whatever.html' }
    });
```

Comment: You need to bind this function to the dialog. You can't dynamically tell the dialog to do this when the dialog is already displayed. It looks like you're using the documentation's verbatim example, so just use the bind example in the same demo.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Yes you can, all jQuery UI widgets support the option method (`$(x).dialog('option', ...)`) for change options on a widget that already exists.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm sorry, but you're wrong. If the dialog `is already open, you cannot change the methods of that open dialog` you can change it so that the `next dialog that opens has those methods` but you cannot `add methods to a dialog that is already open`. Go ahead and try it. Let me know your findings.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: My findings are [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/nuGqK/) and even [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kfQr6/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`option` method](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#method-option) to change options on an existing jQuery UI widget:

```
$('#myDialog').dialog('option', 'close', function(event, ui) { ... });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/nuGqK/

This should work for any dialog option.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind this event to already created jquery dialog like this,

```
$( "#myDialog" ).bind( "dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
location.href = 'whatever.html' ;
});
```